# MEANStack tutorial on thinkster, route parameter doens't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following a MEAN tutorial on Thinkster (https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) and can't find a sollution for passing the route parameter.

My problem comes from this section in the tutorial (https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#the-posts-page)

When I want to see the comments of a post (by passing the route parameter in my URL). The tutorial says :

> For now, we will consider the index of the post to be its id. We can use $stateParams to retrieve the id from the URL and load the appropriate post.

Using the folowing code :

```
$scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
<span>
  <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
</span>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. But I don't think my code runs through the PostCtrl controller.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>
        .glyphicon-thumbs-up {
            cursor: pointer
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
            <!-- Waar de template moet geplaatst worden in actieve state !-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Home state !-->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
  </div>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span> {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
        </span>
        <span>
  <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
</span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</script>


    <!-- Posts state !-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>
                <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                    {{post.title}}
                </a>
                <span ng-hide="post.link">
                    {{post.title}}
                </span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comment | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
             ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
             {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
                <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
             {{comment.body}}
            </span>
        </div>
</script>

    <!-- Andere state !-->

</body>

</html>

    var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
]);

/* We creeeren een nieuw object dat een property posts heeft. 
We geven dan die variabele (o) terug zodat deze door elke angular module kan gebruikt worden. 
Je kan hier ook methode in exporteren
$scope.posts = posts.posts in MainCtrl --> Nu wordt elke wijziging opgeslaan in de service*/
app.factory('posts', [function () {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'posts',
    function ($scope, posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts.posts

        $scope.posts = [{
            title: 'post 1',
            upvotes: 5
        }, {
            title: 'post 2',
            upvotes: 2
        }, {
            title: 'post 3',
            upvotes: 15
        }, {
            title: 'post 4',
            upvotes: 9
        }, {
            title: 'post 5',
            upvotes: 4
        }];

        $scope.addPost = function () {
            if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
                return;
            }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
                upvotes: 0,
                comments: [{
                    author: 'Joe',
                    body: 'Cool post!',
                    upvotes: 0
                }, {
                    author: 'Bob',
                    body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!',
                    upvotes: 0
                }]
            });
            $scope.title = '';
            $scope.link = '';
        };

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function (post) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };
    }
]);
app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    'post',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, posts, post) {
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    }
]);
```

Comment: This (and its answer if it helped you) sounds like something you might want to contact thinkster.io about. I'm sure they would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You have *re-declared* `$scope.posts` in your `MainCtrl`, so changes in `MainCtrl` are never being reflected in your `posts` factory.

The problem is at:

```js
 $scope.posts = posts.posts;

 $scope.posts = [{
   title: 'post 1',
   upvotes: 5
 }, {
   title: 'post 2',
   upvotes: 2
 }, {
   title: 'post 3',
   upvotes: 15
 }, {
   title: 'post 4',
   upvotes: 9
 }, {
   title: 'post 5',
   upvotes: 4
 }];
```

The first statement is setting `$scope.posts` equal to your factory object, the second is setting it to a local array.

You should instead use `push` to add your data into the factory array.

```js
$scope.posts = posts.posts;

$scope.posts.push({
  title: 'post 1',
  upvotes: 5
}, {
  title: 'post 2',
  upvotes: 2
}, {
  title: 'post 3',
  upvotes: 15
}, {
  title: 'post 4',
  upvotes: 9
}, {
  title: 'post 5',
  upvotes: 4
});​
```

Also, you have an extra injection in your `PostsCtrl`, there is no `post` service to be injected.

A full working copy of your code with relevant changes is on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLGwmyUksSmXaTZvjNTO?p=preview).

Comment: The key to remember here is that you can change the *properties* of an object but not the **entire** object.